# Bizarre Sudden Slow-Down of Specific MacOS Processes

Tags: macos, terminal, network, performance, visual-studio-code

I purchased a 2020 M1 13" MacBook Pro in March 2021 and it's been like driving a racing car. I use it for everything, and I do a lot as I'm a post-graduate researcher in Electrical Engineering. This machine has been great and I've had no issues, until now...

## What's Happened:

---

Certain apps/commands in terminal are incredibly slow to execute. Specific examples that I've observed:

- `git status` *[several minutes to process]*
- Apple's built-in screenshot tool (mapped to button on touch-bar) *[15-30 seconds to open]*
- Apple's built-in dictation *[not yet waited long enough for it to be ready]*
- Apple's archive utility *[30-60 seconds to process]*
- Apple's terminal shell prompt *[several minutes to be ready]*

  - This has also been observed via the terminal in VSCode
- Running a Ruby Jekyll local server via VSCode (or via terminal) *[**11 minutes** to process]*

The previously longest process from the above list would be the Ruby Jekyll server, which previously took <2 seconds to process. Now it's 11 minutes...

## When/How Did it Start:

---

I was using the machine fairly heavily for work and leisure as usual. I was about to go on holiday for 2 weeks so I shut it down and left it in a drawer, as I wasn't taking it with me. I returned, booted it, and immediately all of these issues have presented.

## Potential Causes I Have Disproven:

---

- **Hardware issues** - Apple diagnostics return no issues
- **Low disk space** - 237 GB remaining on a 500 GB SSD
- **Updates** - I have not run any specific system wide updates before or after the start of this issue
- **Malware** - virus scans with Avast and Malwarebytes return no finds

  - All potentially suspicious software recently installed has been completely removed during my diagnostics

## Attempted Remedies that Haven't Worked:

---

- Updating git
- Clearing more disk space
- Deleting all data in `/Users/<username>/.zsh_sessions`
- Deleting all data in `/private/var/log/asl`
- Deleting `/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`
- Inspecting `.zshrc` - no changes there for a long time
- Rebooting (I generally reboot once every 3 months (usually by which time the machine has crashed) however I have tried several reboots with no improvements)

## Related Observations:

---

- This does not affect overall system performance. When processes are stuck, the rest of the machine appears to be operating entirely normally. CPU usage is around 10% - no beachball of death
- This does not affect all apps - I can open and close Chrome with no issue, for example. Only certain apps are affected
- I can open VSCode (for example) without a delay about two-thirds of the time. The other third, there is a delay of 15-30 seconds. There then may or may not be a 1-3 minute delay for the shell prompt to become available when I open the terminal pane
- Once an app/process has successfully worked through a delay, it generally won't experience one for the next 12-24 hours

  - After a delay with `git status`, there were then no delays with `git status`. There was then, however, a delay with `git push` (not `add` or `commit`, run inbetween). There were then no delays with `git push` that day, thus the delays are not wholly persistent
- Once an app/command finally runs, it will usually be as quick as before to execute (with the exception of `bundle exec jekyll serve -l` which can still process slowly once started)
- I had narrowed it down to the shell, as it is commands executed here and it's use within VSCode that were the primary symptoms, hence my deleting of various logs and `.plist`'s, however I am no longer so sure
- Disconnecting from the internet **does** appear to be a workaround, that causes the processes to complete immediately

  - I have used Wireshark to inspect my network traffic during hangs. There is some TCP communication to Apple servers, but that's about it
  - This is not related to internet connectivity, speeds, or firewalls. I have the same issues at home and at my university campus (with ~850 MB/s download speeds)

    - Other Mac users on both of those networks do not report issues
    - I do run LuLu, but haven't modified any settings in recent months. Disabling LuLu hasn't helped
  - I assume this is not an issue on Apple's side as other Mac users are not suffering with this

### System Details:

(as far as I can see would be relevant)

---

- M1 MacBook Pro
- 16 GB RAM
- 500 GB SSD
- Big Sur 11.1
- Git 2.42.0
- Ruby 3.2.2
- Jekyll 4.3.2
- Chrome 117.0.5938.62
- VSCode 1.82.1

---

As you can imagine, waiting minutes (or even 11) for what were previously small, slick operations to take place is infuriating. I believe there is some sort of delay with my machine verifying certain apps/processes with Apple's servers, but I am at a loss as to what could be the underlying cause, especially as everything *was* running fine, and then suddenly *wasn't*.

I have been unable to find any new advice that I haven't tried already so am now reaching out (usually my last resort).

I welcome all and any advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest you start by removing your useless "anti-virus" software, which you should do regardless of whether or not it's causing this problem. If. after doing that, there's no improvement, start up in safe mode and test.